# TFS web access attachements drag and drop

Tags: tfs

I know it is possible to drag and drop files or for example mails from Outlook to Attachement tab in VS (if VS was started as Administrator Outlook should also run under this account).

But I was not able to find out if this is also possible with web Access...I tried but it was not successfull. I could drag and drop an email to a text box (text is added) but not to attachment control...is this not possible?! We are running TFS 2015 as on premise.

Greetings,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be implemented yet in Visual Studio Online, so I can't think it would be in any of the on premises versions of TFS.

I've just tried in Edge and you get an overlay on the image showing it's not allowed:

[image: Not allowed to drag]

You could suggest this on the [Visual Studio User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com) or ask [Aaron Bjork](https://twitter.com/aaronbjork) who's the Program Manager for Work Item tracking.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer and the links. I think I will ask Aaron Bjork first.